# How to loop a video back and forth with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video of `5s` length. The final video should be `60s` long.
The resulting video should be a "ping pong" loop, meaning my 5s should be played back and forth until the 60s are reached.

Does someone know the `ffmpeg` magic to do this?

My ffmpeg version:

```
ffmpeg version 3.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
```

Comment: "ping pong" you mean played forwards, then backwards, then forwards etc?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes exactly :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -filter_complex "[0]reverse[r];[0][r]concat,loop=5:250,setpts=N/25/TB" output.mp4
```

In `loop=5:250`, `5` is number of loops, `250` is`frame rate x double length of clip`. The `setpts` is applied to avoid frame drops, and the value `25` should be replaced with the framerate of the clip.

Comment: Trying this I get: `[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fdd02c16900] No such filter: 'loop'`
On this thread http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/repeat-loop-input-video-with-ffmpeg it is mentioned that the loop filter only applies for images/gifs?

Comment: Looks like you have an old version. The loop filter was added in mid-Feb.

Comment: I added info about my ffmpeg version

Comment: Loop filter was added on Feb 18, and your binary's codebase is Feb 14. You'll need a recent nightly.

Comment: I am using compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2' in android but error   [AVFilterGraph @ 0xab008040] No such filter: 'loop' how i am resolve